# Spring Security FlywayDB - Generating a default user

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

Spring Boot Web application, Spring Data JPA, Spring Security, FlywayDB.

SQL

```
INSERT INTO USER(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PASSWORD, USER_GROUP) values('D', 'J', 'D@J.com', '123', 'ROLE_USER');
```

Security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);

    }
}
```

When I try to login using the user I created with FlywayDB migration it doesn't work. I get back the error message "bad credentials". No other errors during execution.

Have I missed configuring something?

Comment: "passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder)" - did you enter the hash in to the database or a plaintext password? if plaintext it is going to fail.

Comment: I entered "123". How do I enter the hash? I tried some BCryptHashGenerator online but that didn't work either.

Comment: Try the following Java code: (new BCryptPasswordEncoder()).encode("password");

Comment: Problem is, I'm using FlyWayDB to insert the user in to the DB. And that's using SQL.

Comment: You could generate a hash using that code and then place the output in the SQL statement unless I am missing something.

Comment: Use something like [this](https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator) to generate the BCrypt hash for the password and enter that into the database. Never store plaintext passwords.